# Angular JS Route: attach more than one controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

can be possible to attach more than one controller to a route, like an array of controllers?

In *'/store'*, I need to attach **"StoreController" and "ReviewController"**, without repeating **.when()** so many times:

my code:

```
angular  
  .module('gemStore', [
    'example-directives'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

      .when('/store', {
        templateUrl: 'store.html',
        controller: 'StoreController'
      })

      .when('/store', {
        templateUrl: 'store.html',
        controller: 'ReviewController'
      }) 

      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

  });
```

Comment: No there is no way to pass an array of controllers. I'm pretty certain that you're doing it wrong.  :(  . Each page should have only one controller at it's root. What you need is one parent controller for '/store' and have two other controllers as children under that controller. The two other controllers would be declared in the HTML with ng-controller. I'm curious to see what happens when this code actually runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What should happen is you should have ONLY ONE 'root' controller for a page, and any 'parts' of the page should be children of the root controller.

```
$routeProvider

  .when('/store', {
    templateUrl: 'store.html',
    controller: 'StoreParentController'
  })
```

Then children can be declared in the HTML like so:

```
<div ng-controller="StoreParentController"> <!-- you dont need this particular controller here because you have it in your routeprovider, this is just an example of the structure-->
    <div ng-controller="StoreController"> stuff about store </div>
    <div ng-controller="ReviewsController"> reviews </div>
</div>
```